# How is running the asset_management.go different from running a simple chaincode like chaincode_example02.go

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

The simple workflow for deploying/invoking a chaincode (to my knowledge) is :

1. Deploy a chaincode(smart contract) on the blockchain

   - This brings up a docker container on all peers that has the chaincode running in it
2. Invoke some function

   - This type of function changes the values of variables in chaincode state

For [asset_management.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/chaincode/go/asset_management/asset_management.go), the chaincode can be tested by running `go test` in the asset_management chaincode directory . But this does not really bring up a docker container(or does it ?) that runs the asset_management chaincode.

Whats the right way to deploy/invoke this chaincode and how is it different from deploying/invoking chaincodes using the REST interface(like we do for [chaincode_example02](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02/chaincode_example02.go))

Answer (score 3):

The chaincode workflow you mentioned is correct, just one detail regarding variables in chaincode state: the variables are stored in a global key-value collection named [World State](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/protocol-spec.md#322-world-state), which is accessed through the invocation of a chaincode and it is [access protected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024955/can-a-world-state-variable-be-accessed-by-a-chaincode-different-from-the-one-tha/37024956#37024956).

Now, what you are doing with [go test](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/) is running the code in [asset_management_test.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/chaincode/go/asset_management/asset_management_test.go). If you look at this code, you will see that it basically starts a VP and a CA and then tries sending transactions to tests that the chaincode works. For example:

```
// Now create the Transactions message and send to Peer.
transaction, err := txHandler.NewChaincodeExecute(chaincodeInvocationSpec, tid)
```

You could also code a test file for the chaincode_example02 and test it.

Or you can also deploy the asset_management chaincode the same way you use to deploy chaincode_example02. Which can be using a [chaincode development environment](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/API/SandboxSetup.md) or a [development network](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/dev-setup/devnet-setup.md).

**Important:** asset_management chaincode is used to test the [invocation access control](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/protocol-spec.md#44-access-control-features-on-the-application), so it is fairly complex. Invoking its methods means using digital signatures to check the identity of the chaincode invoker. You can check the asset_management_test file to see how it is done.

Answer (score 3):

The list of steps for anybody who would like to run “asset_management_with_roles” manually:

1. Checkout Fabric, run vagrant from “devenv” folder
2. ssh to the started container.
3. Reset Fabric’s configuration:

   ```
   rm /var/hyperledger/production
   ```
4. Enable attribute certificate authority in membersrvc.yaml

   ```
   aca.enabled: true
   ```
5. Enable security in core.yaml

   ```
   security.enable: true
   ```
6. Switch log level for “node” to “debug” in core.yaml (optional. not necessary if you know the certificates)

   ```
   logging.node: debug
   ```
7. Run membersrvc in background:

   ```
   nohup membersrvc &> /tmp/membersrvc.log &
   ```
8. Run peer service

   ```
   peer node start
   ```
9. Verify if users “assigner, bob, alice” are in membersrvc.yaml, according to the comment in this example we will work with:

   `// This example implements asset transfer using attributes support and specifically Attribute Based Access Control (ABAC). 
   // There are three users in this example: 
   // - alice 
   // - bob 
   // - assigner 
   // 
   // This users are defined in the section “eca" of asset.yaml file. 
   // In the section “aca" of asset.yaml file two attributes are defined to this users: 
   // The first attribute is called ‘role' with this values: 
   // - alice has role = client 
   // - bob has role = client 
   // - assigner has role = assigner 
   // 
   // The second attribute is called ‘account' with this values: 
   // - alice has account = 12345-56789 
   // - bob has account = 23456-67890`

   Open another ssh terminal with vagrant and login to the network:

   ```
   peer network login assigner -p Tc43PeqBl11
   peer network login bob -p NOE63pEQbL25
   peer network login alice -p CMS10pEQlB16
   ```

8. Deploy chaincode to the network using “assigner” security context:

```
curl -XPOST -d ‘{“jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "deploy", "params": {"type": 1,"chaincodeID": {"path": "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/asset_management_with_roles","language": "GOLANG"}, "ctorMsg": { "args": ["init"] }, "metadata":[97, 115, 115, 105, 103, 110, 101, 114] ,"secureContext": "assigner"} ,"id": 0}' http://localhost:7050/chaincode
```

metadata contains utf-8 encoded string “assigner”. This string will be saved in a ledger and only user with such role will be able to execute “assign” function in smart contract.

In order to keep example readable lets save chaincode id in local variable:

```
export HASH=7adc030881c07c39d2edac0b1560bf7cf2b7f0a4bce74fe7e6144e3f36e1bf2d176093d4c23ba58712a9589d9600e6d9ef596a1521a4c5227c222d8af2bf16c8
```

9. Starting from this moment user “assigner” can create new assets for bob and alice, we just have to find their certificates.
   let’s run query command for any random asset name under “bob” securityContext:

   ```
   curl -XPOST -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "query", "params": {"type": 1, "chaincodeID": {"name": "'"$HASH"'"}, "ctorMsg": {"args": ["query", "myasset"]}, "secureContext": "bob", "attributes": ["role", "account"]}, "id": 1}' http://localhost:7050/chaincode
   ```

   (IMPORTANT: without `“attributes”: [“role”, “account”]` no attributes will be loaded into transactions certificate)

   As far as “peer” is started in debug mode, bob’s certificate will be printed in peer log output. Try to find row “[client.bob] Adding new Cert” and copy certificate value:

   `30 82 02 90 30 82 02 37 a0 03 02 01 02 02 10 2f 9e 4e da c9 e9 4e 97 b1 58 24 78 4e 15 05 f4 30 0a 06 08 2a 86 48 ce 3d 04 03 03 30 31 31 0b 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 55 53 31 14 30 12 06 03 55 04 0a 13 0b 48 79 70 65 72 6c 65 64 67 65 72 31 0c 30 0a 06 03 55 04 03 13 03 74 63 61 30 1e 17 0d 31 36 30 39 31 39 32 31 32 34 31 39 5a 17 0d 31 36 31 32 31 38 32 31 32 34 31 39 5a 30 45 31 0b 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 55 53 31 14 30 12 06 03 55 04 0a 13 0b 48 79 70 65 72 6c 65 64 67 65 72 31 20 30 1e 06 03 55 04 03 13 17 54 72 61 6e 73 61 63 74 69 6f 6e 20 43 65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74 65 30 59 30 13 06 07 2a 86 48 ce 3d 02 01 06 08 2a 86 48 ce 3d 03 01 07 03 42 00 04 78 8f f2 11 55 a3 5a 8d f1 b5 4f 38 e4 94 e4 67 b0 47 7f e0 07 04 b8 fb 12 ee 86 17 8a 05 55 e3 98 f6 c1 af 59 ee 2d 54 a9 c5 36 22 cd fa a8 1b ce ba e0 26 fd 73 40 af 20 5d 15 65 89 9c 62 64 a3 82 01 1b 30 82 01 17 30 0e 06 03 55 1d 0f 01 01 ff 04 04 03 02 07 80 30 0c 06 03 55 1d 13 01 01 ff 04 02 30 00 30 0d 06 03 55 1d 0e 04 06 04 04 01 02 03 04 30 0f 06 03 55 1d 23 04 08 30 06 80 04 01 02 03 04 30 10 06 06 2a 03 04 05 06 0a 04 06 63 6c 69 65 6e 74 30 15 06 06 2a 03 04 05 06 0b 04 0b 32 33 34 35 36 2d 36 37 38 39 30 30 4d 06 06 2a 03 04 05 06 07 01 01 ff 04 40 fc c2 07 dd ee ac 8c 76 84 12 07 d2 e0 a6 da b3 06 c9 5b 5b 41 57 a3 f3 a2 f7 59 e2 ed 02 02 7e 56 46 f5 bc 24 00 0a 2e 18 b4 a6 b7 a6 c3 8d ca 15 13 a7 98 42 98 8f 9b 85 a2 d1 6a 77 0d da e8 30 3a 06 06 2a 03 04 05 06 08 04 30 ff d2 ab 7f c8 2d 98 c4 3f c9 f7 05 12 07 01 3a 36 69 f8 ee d1 c4 27 16 48 3e ee ed db b9 b6 3c d6 e5 1a 3e 0b 7d f0 19 1c 81 03 12 f6 7b d5 3e 30 23 06 06 2a 03 04 05 06 09 04 19 30 30 48 45 41 44 72 6f 6c 65 2d 3e 31 23 61 63 63 6f 75 6e 74 2d 3e 32 23 30 0a 06 08 2a 86 48 ce 3d 04 03 03 03 47 00 30 44 02 20 49 52 26 bd b8 f4 a0 98 c6 ff fc 56 3e b5 b0 12 ee ec b7 46 90 55 b1 17 99 29 fe df 80 2e 95 b9 02 20 3b 7f dd 32 88 56 ae a1 14 60 54 60 95 61 fb d1 bc 0c f7 e0 61 f2 e9 0b 46 35 6a 36 61 c9 b8 f0`
10. Certificate should be based64 encoded. As an option we can use http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en

    Insert certificate into “Hex string” field, click “convert” button, and result will be in “Output (base64)”:

    `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`
11. "assign" method expects 2 parameters the Name for asset and owner certificate. New asset can be created using:

    `curl -XPOST -d  '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "invoke", "params": {"type": 1, "chaincodeID": {"name": "'"$HASH"'"}, "ctorMsg": {"args": ["assign", "myasset", "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"]}, "metadata":[97, 115, 115, 105, 103, 110, 101, 114], "secureContext": "assigner", "attributes": ["role", "account"]}, "id": 1}' http://localhost:7050/chaincode`
12. Try to run the query from step 9 for bob again:

    ```
    curl -XPOST -d ‘{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "query", "params": {"type": 1, "chaincodeID": {"name": "'"$HASH"'"}, "ctorMsg": {"args": ["query", "myasset"]}, "secureContext": "bob", "attributes": ["role", "account"]}, "id": 1}' http://localhost:7050/chaincode
    ```

    and you will see that “myasset” is already created, and belongs to account “23456-67890”
13. Using the same approach we can find certificate for alice and change the owner for “myasset”.