# Why is the user certificate empty in chaincode?

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to deploy chaincode to a network that includes 4 peers and a membership service in IBM Bluemix.

I've registered user "admin", and it has a certificate.

The chaincode is from example asset_management.

On deploy-init, chaincode fails on line :

> adminCert, err := stub.GetCallerMetadata()

```
if err != nil {
    myLogger.Debug("Failed getting metadata")
    return nil, errors.New("Failed getting metadata.")
}

if len(adminCert) == 0 {
    myLogger.Debug("Invalid admin certificate. Empty.")
    return nil, errors.New("Invalid admin certificate. Empty.")
}
```

The admin certificate is empty. 
Why does the chaincode not get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find explanation for how to work with asset_management example in related question:
[How is running the asset_management.go different from running a simple chaincode like chaincode_example02.go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021057/how-is-running-the-asset-management-go-different-from-running-a-simple-chaincode/39582897#39582897)

But instead of extracting the certificate from the log, now we can use node.js SDK:
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/master/docs/node-sdk-indepth.md

Comment: what about signature ? Metadata is the chaincodeinput and binding signed with certificate. Can i sign it the same using java for example ?

Comment: It should be possible soon when Fabric v1 will be released. In current version privacy/encryption for Java is not available.